# Turtle Graphics- difference between .home and .setpos(0,0)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

what is the difference between .home and .setpos(0,0)?

Turtle home basically is setting the turtle back to coordinates (0,0) and setpos(0,0) is also the same thing then what is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's useful to look into documentation first, in case you have any questions. Typically most of answers could be found here

For example documentation of [`.home()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.home)

> **turtle.home()**
>
> Move turtle to the origin – coordinates (0,0) – and set its heading to its start orientation (which depends on the mode, see mode()).

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setpos) you can see that setpos() does not change the orientation of the turtle, [home()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.home) instead resets the orientation according to the current [mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.mode).